# Custom Iterator and method chaining in Java

Tags: java

I have a problem with my custom iterator, so I'm asking for your help. I have class MyIterator, which is an iterator with transformation. This class has methods:

- *next()* - returns next element
- *hasNext()* - check if next element exists
- *fromIterator* - static method, which converts Iterator to MyIterator
- *map* - method which takes functional interface and returns MyIterator with transformation rule corresponding to this interface
- *forEach* - method which takes functional interface and iterates over all remaining objects according to the interface. 
   
   My realisation is

```
    import java.util.Iterator;
    import java.util.function.Consumer;
    import java.util.function.Function;

    public class MyIterator<K, V> {
        private final Iterator<K> iterator;
        private final Function<K, V> function;

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public static <K, V> MyIterator<K, V> fromIterator(Iterator<K> iterator) {
            return new MyIterator<>(iterator, k -> (V) k);
        }

        private MyIterator(Iterator<K> iterator, Function<K, V> function) {
            this.iterator = iterator;
            this.function = function;
        }

        public V next() {
            return this.function.apply(iterator.next());
        }

        public boolean hasNext() {
            return this.iterator.hasNext();
        }

        public MyIterator<K, V> map(Function<K, V> function) {
            return new MyIterator<K, V>(this.iterator, this.function);
        }

        public void forEach(Consumer<V> action) {
            while (hasNext()) {
                action.accept(this.next());
            }
        }
    }
```

So, I did this task, but I can't understand, **how to change the method *map* into chaining method (pipeline)**. I mean the following:

```
    MyIterator<String, Integer> myIterator3 = MyIterator.fromIterator(stringsArray.iterator()).map(s -> s.length()).map(i -> i.toString()).map(s -> s.length());
```

For example, I have String "England". After first map I want to get 7 ("England" consists of 7 characters), than "7", than 1 (because String "7" consists of 1 character). 
 My assumption is that I should use methods *andThen/compose* in my method map, by I can't understand, how.

Comment: Firstly, your `map` method takes a function as a parameter which you completely ignore.

Comment: Why do you think an iterator needs two generic type parameters? K and V traditionally stand for "key" and "value". They don't make sense in this context. This `k -> (V) k` should act as a clue that what you're doing does not make a lot of sense

Comment: @Michael, thank you for answer! I use two generic type parameters, because otherwise I won't be able to have Function<K, V> as a field of my class. You also wrote about map method which ignores function, I understand it, but I can't figure out how to use this function apart from this: return new MyIterator (it is neccessary) with the function field, where the function that looks like f1.compose(f2).compose(f3). e.t.c., depends on how many times .map was called on this MyIterator object. Anyway,  I really can't grip how to. So, is it rirght?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: @Michael, I tried it, but it didn't work, because method andThen requires Function<V, V>, so I can't just write `return new MyIterator(this.iterator, this.function.andThen(function));`. Therefore, this approach is incorrect or I don't understand how this function works

Comment: Change signature to `public <T> MyIterator<K, T> map(Function<V, T> function)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `Iterator` accepts one parameter, here is how I modified your code.

```
public class ChainedIterator<T> {

    private Function<T, ?> action;

    private ChainedIterator<T> chain;

    private final Iterator<?> iterator;

    private <R> ChainedIterator(Iterator<?> iterator, Function<T, R> action, ChainedIterator<T> prev) {
      this.action = action;
      this.chain = prev;
      this.iterator = iterator;
    }

    public static <T> ChainedIterator<T> fromIterator(Iterator<T> iterator) {
      return new ChainedIterator<>(iterator, Function.identity(), null);
    }

    public T next() {
      return (T) this.action.apply((T) (Objects.nonNull(this.chain) ? this.chain.next() : this.iterator.next()));
    }

    public boolean hasNext() {
      return this.iterator.hasNext();
    }

    public <R> ChainedIterator<R> map(Function<T, R> action) {
      return new ChainedIterator(this.iterator, action, this);
    }

    public void forEach(Consumer<T> action) {
      while (hasNext()) {
        action.accept(this.next());
      }
    }
 }
```

Usage Example

```
Iterator<String> stringIterator = Arrays.asList("England", "India").iterator();

ChainedIterator<Integer> iterator = ChainedIterator.fromIterator(stringIterator)
  .map(s -> s.length())
  .map(i -> String.valueOf(i))
  .map(s -> s.length());
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you, lucid! Very elegant and concise solution! It helps :)

Answer (score 2):

Update your custom Iterator and allow `fromIterator()` takes function rather you define it

```
public class MyIterator<K, V> {

    private Iterator<K> iterator;
    private List<Function<K, ?>> functions;

    public static <K, V> MyIterator<K, V> fromIterator(Iterator<K> iterator) {
        return new MyIterator<>(iterator);
    }

    private MyIterator(Iterator<K> iterator) {
        this.iterator = iterator;
        functions = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    private MyIterator(Iterator<K> iterator, Function<K, ?> function) {
        this.iterator = iterator;
        functions = new ArrayList<>();
        functions.add(function);
    }

    private MyIterator(Iterator<K> iterator, List<Function<K, ?>> functions) {
        this.iterator = iterator;
        this.functions = functions;
    }

    public Object next() {
        K key = iterator.next();
        Object val = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < functions.size(); i++) {
            val = functions.get(i).apply(key);
            key = (K) val;
        }
        return val;
    }

    public boolean hasNext() {
        return iterator.hasNext();
    }

    public <R, RR> MyIterator<R, RR> map(Function<K, R> function) {
        List<Function<K, ?>> functions2 = this.functions;
        functions2.add(function);
        return new MyIterator(iterator, functions2);
    }

    public void forEach(Consumer<Object> action) {
        while (hasNext()) {
            action.accept(next());
        }
    }
}
```

, main

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Iterator<String> sIterator = Arrays.asList("aaa", "bbbb", "cccc", "ddddd").iterator();
        MyIterator.<String, Object>fromIterator(sIterator).map(s -> s.length()).map(i -> i + "")
                .map(str -> str.length()).forEach(System.out::println);
    }
```

, output

```
1
1
1
1
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but it doesn't work as I asked for. I wanted to get chaining logic, `.map(s -> s.length()).map(i -> Integer.toString(i)).map(s -> s.length())`. so, for "aaa" the result should be 1 ("aaa"->3->"3"->1)

Comment: understand your idea,it works! thank you a lot :D, Also, may I ask a question: is it possible to do it like I mentioned above (using `andThen` or `compose`, without List<> field or I'm wrong?

Comment: I have tested the above code and it compiles. it's building the map from the previous result `R` to be `K` in next map

Comment: above code, it's a simple one, and I didn't try with `compose/then` you can give a try

Comment: sure, sorry, a missed it. It is a good decision, thank you for help and explanations, sc0der! Can you answer a last question in my last comment, please? You obviously have more experience and I would be grateful to you! :)